# Error while process Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-intent, progressdialog, android-intentservice

Logcat:

FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[BMI]
                                                              Process: user.com.test2, PID: 3377
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                  at services.SendBpRecordServer.onHandleIntent(SendBpRecordServer.java:66)
                                                                  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

**What I am trying to do:**

I am fetching data from server using volley and to do operation in background using `IntentService`. And also using `ResultReceiver` to get the data from the service to activity.

`UpdateData.class`

```
public class Updatedata extends AppCompatActivity implements MyResultReceiver.Receiver{
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    public MyResultReceiver resultReceiver, resultReceiverBMI, resultReceiverBP;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notify);
        Log.i("On Creste","Yes");
        dbHelper=new DbHelper(this);
        //before starting further empty all the tables
        dbHelper.emptyTables();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(Updatedata.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Fetching Profile Data");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();
            resultReceiver=new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());
            resultReceiver.setReceiver(this);
            System.out.println("Fetch Diabetes Data Service "+ SendDiabetesRecordServer.TAG);
            Intent intent=new Intent(this, SendDiabetesRecordServer.class);
            intent.putExtra("nameTag","fetch");
            intent.putExtra("receiverTag",resultReceiver);
            startService(intent);
            Log.i("Fetch BMI Data ", SendBmiRecordServer.TAG);
            resultReceiverBMI=new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());
            resultReceiverBMI.setReceiver(this);
            Intent intent1=new Intent(this,SendBmiRecordServer.class);
            intent1.putExtra("nameTag","fetch");
            intent1.putExtra("receiverTagBMI",resultReceiverBMI);
            startService(intent1);
            Log.i("Fetch BP Data ", SendBpRecordServer.TAG);
            resultReceiverBP=new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());
            resultReceiverBP.setReceiver(this);
             Intent intent2=new Intent(this,SendBpRecordServer.class);
             intent2.putExtra("nameTag","fetch");
             intent2.putExtra("receiverTagBP",resultReceiverBP);
             startService(intent2);
        /*if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }*/
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Diabetes","received result from Service= "+resultData.getString("ServiceTag"));
        Log.d("BMI ","received result from Service= "+resultData.getString("ServiceTag"));
       /* if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }*/
        Log.i("Get Values ",Integer.toString(Constants.getValues));
        if (resultCode==0 && resultData.getBoolean("Process_Complete"))
            Constants.getValues++;
        if (resultCode==1 && resultData.getBoolean("Process_Complete_bmi"))
            Constants.getValues++;
        if (resultCode==2 && resultData.getBoolean("Process_Complete_bp"))
            Constants.getValues++;
        if (Constants.getValues==3)
        {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

`IntentService` Template:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    String recName=intent.getStringExtra("nameTag");

    if (recName.equals("fetch"))
    {


        fetchDatFromServer();

        ResultReceiver resultReceiver=intent.getParcelableExtra("receiverTag");

        Log.d("diabetes Reseult ",resultReceiver.toString());

        Bundle b= new Bundle();
        b.putBoolean("Process_Complete",true);
        resultReceiver.send(0, b);
    }
```

This is same for 3 `IntentService`.

Error Getting At:-

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    String recName=intent.getStringExtra("nameTag");

    if (recName.equals("fetch"))
    {
        Log.i("Send Data","Yes");
        fetchDatFromServer();

        ResultReceiver resultReceiver=intent.getParcelableExtra("receiverTag");

        **Log.d("BP Reseult ",resultReceiver.toString());**  //Getting Error at this line

        Bundle bun= new Bundle();
        bun.putBoolean("Process_Complete_bp",true);
        resultReceiver.send(2, bun);

    }
```

**Debugging:**

In the second intent class i.e `SendBmiRecordServer.class`

I am very sure the problem is in this class only. 
because when I put the `Log.i("Get Values", Constants.getValues);`
and I have initialize `Constants.getValues=0` in `Constants.class`

This I am getting the result till 1

Comment: Wherever you are trying to show the progressDialog check !isFinishing() then only show the progressDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Override onDestroy method and do the following

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
              if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Is your activity still open?

Comment: Which means your Activity is active or closed?

Comment: Then try to check the onDestroy method is called or not?

Comment: onDestroy() called one times

Comment: Actually which line of code u r getting the error?

user.com.hlthee.Updatedata.onCreate(Updatedata.java:44

Comment: Hey thanks.. I got the solution.. I have typo error.. can you bit explain when onDestroy() will call.. One more problem.. Process Dialog is not showing.

Comment: Refer the link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29

Comment: ok,, thanks.. can you tell me why I am not able to see process dialog,

Comment: I don't know the exact scenario. Just try to comment from this line  resultReceiver=new MyResultReceiver(new Handler()); to startService(intent2); and check the dialog.

Comment: I debug more.. but what I find out that process dialog is showing but for just for seconds instead of the task completed.

Comment: why it is killed..  updateData is used to call all the intent service to fetch data from server. and it is working perfectly..